# Average time to run an assert statement in RUBY?

Tags: ruby, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver

I know this is a bit of an open ended question, but I've just taken over running an automation pack which uses RUBY and need to make performance improvements to it.

I'm wondering if anyone may have some idea of how long it takes to run a simple assert (true, false, equal, etc) in Ruby?

Some of the tests are very long running and include a lot of asserts (one test has over 7000!).

Being able to eliminate even just a few asserts which are frequently called could help a lot. I just need to be able to demonstrate the benefit on paper to my manager before we spend time refactoring.

Any help you can provide appreciated by this newbie!!
Thanks,
Tufty

Comment: just keep in mind, a test without assertions isn't really a test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assertions themselves are very fast. In the following spec, you can see that 14,000 assertions can easily be made in less than a second.

```
require 'rspec/autorun'

RSpec.describe 'assert' do
  it 'is fast for a simple comparision' do
    7000.times { expect(1).to eq(1) }
  end

  it 'is fast for include' do
    7000.times { expect("aasdfas flsajfalds jfdsf lksa jfd test asfdsadf sadfsadf").to include('test') }
  end
end
#=> Finished in 0.0312 seconds (files took 0.1092 seconds to load)
#=> 2 examples, 0 failures
```

It is the inspecting of the browser that makes the assertions slow. In the following spec, you can see that it takes 50 seconds just to inspect the text *100* times.

```
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'watir-webdriver'

RSpec.describe 'assert url' do
  it 'is fast for include' do
    start_setup = Time.now
    browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
    browser.goto('http://www.example.com/')
    puts "start browser: #{Time.now - start_setup} seconds"

    100.times { expect(browser.text).to include('illustrative') }
  end
end
#=> start browser: 1.947 seconds
#=> Finished in 52.92 seconds (files took 0.441 seconds to load)
#=> 1 example, 0 failures
```

Removing duplicate calls to the browser, allows us to again make many assertions quickly (aside from the browser setup).

```
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'watir-webdriver'

RSpec.describe 'assert url' do
  it 'is fast for include' do
    start_setup = Time.now
    browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
    browser.goto('http://www.example.com/')
    puts "start browser: #{Time.now - start_setup} seconds"

    text = browser.text
    7000.times { expect(text).to include('illustrative') }
    7000.times { expect(text).not_to include('some other text') }
  end
end
#=> start browser: 1.972 seconds
#=> Finished in 2.75 seconds (files took 0.3432 seconds to load)
#=> 1 example, 0 failures
```

In summary, assertions are fast, but inspecting the browser is slow. Removing assertions will only speed up your test suite if they reduced the number of calls to the browser.

Comment: Thanks for the demonstration of the assertion times @Justin-Ko, very helpful.  I do think the problem will turn out to be the number of browser calls and recycling through functions which don't ideally need to be replayed.